# Factory method 'dataSource' threw NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, websocket

There was similar question about this problem below, but solutions provided there didn't helped me:
[Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception while startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435957/factory-method-datasource-threw-exception-while-startup)
The problem is that I try to create simple Websocket application with CRUD operations. While running the app after successful build, I got messages as showing on stack trace:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/home/admin1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.8.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2021-09-05 15:31:51.296 ERROR 14659 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception:
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/example/websocket/configuration/DbConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It detects problem inside DbConfig class, which throws NullPointerException. Below is the class DbConfig.java:

```
package com.example.websocket.configuration;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class DbConfig {

    private final Environment env = null;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        assert false;
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

According to question mentioned before, I checked also pom.xml dependencies and settings in application.properties

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ch.simas.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8965
logging.level.root=INFO
spring.jpa.database-platform=com.example.websocket.configuration.SQLiteDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:database.db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC
spring.datasource.username=**
spring.datasource.password=**
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Main application class looks like this:

```
package com.example.websocket;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;

@EnableWebSocket
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebsocketApp{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebsocketApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

If possible, please point out where I did any mistake.
UPDATE
I've changed DbConfig class - removed `assert=false` and added `@Autowired private final Environment env ;` . The NullPointerException disappeared but came a BeanCreation Exception:`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:Receiver class org.sqlite.Conn does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract boolean isValid(int)' of interface java.sql.Connection.`

Answer (score 2):

Your `env` object is `null`:

```
private final Environment env = null;
```

so when in line 21 call

```
env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name")
```

you get the `NullPointerException`.

You should inject (`@Autowired`) the `Environment` in `DbConfig` class as (and remove the `final` modifier):

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class DbConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Also I removed the `assert false;` line, whats the point of it? It will throw a `AssertionError` exception and break your program anyway!

**UPDATE**

For the error:

```
Receiver class org.sqlite.Conn does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract boolean isValid(int)' of interface java.sql.Connection.
```

you have to update your SQLite driver, the version `3.7.2` you are using in your pom.xml is **ancient**! It dates back to 2010!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

use a latest version e.g.

```
<version>3.36.0.3</version>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, the NullPointerException disappeared and now is listed as before issue with "BeanCreationException" refferred to main class "WebsocketApp. It says "Receiver class org.sqlite.Conn does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract boolean isValid(int)' of interface java.sql.Connection."

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `DbConfig`. Simply drop it and use `application.properties` only. Spring Boot will automatically configure a data source based on these properties.